# Birt Images with IText never ends

Tags: image, report, itext, birt

I'm working with Birt reports and, when i want to generate a pdf file, it never ends. The problem is in the line. 
IRunAndRenderTask.run. I have no exception when I create the IBirtEngine. 
Here is the code to create the BirtEngine and the reports designs.

```
private static IReportEngine birtEngine = null;
private static IReportRunnable examenAuditifReportDesign = null;
private static IReportRunnable bilanCollectifReportDesign = null;
private static Properties configProps = new Properties();

static{
        loadEngineProps();//Read the birt configuration properties
        EngineConfig config = new EngineConfig();
        if( configProps != null){
            config.setLogConfig(configProps.getProperty("logDirectory"), Level.INFO);
            config.setBIRTHome(configProps.getProperty("birtHome"));
            config.setResourcePath(configProps.getProperty("ressourcePath"));
            config.setEngineHome(configProps.getProperty("birtHome"));
            config.setProperty("birtReportsHome", configProps.getProperty("birtReportsHome"));
        }
        try {
            RegistryProviderFactory.releaseDefault();
            Platform.startup( config );
        } catch ( BirtException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }

        IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY );
        birtEngine = factory.createReportEngine( config ); 
        try {
            examenAuditifReportDesign = birtEngine.openReportDesign(
                    new FileInputStream(birtEngine.getConfig().getProperty("birtReportsHome")  + "/examenAuditif.rptdesign"));
            bilanCollectifReportDesign = birtEngine.openReportDesign(
                    new FileInputStream(birtEngine.getConfig().getProperty("birtReportsHome")  + "/bilanCollectif.rptdesign"));
        } catch (EngineException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here's the code to execute the reports.

```
IRunAndRenderTask task = birtEngine.createRunAndRenderTask(examenAuditifReportDesign);
task.setParameterValue("RPT_ID_Travailleur", t.getId());  
task.setParameterValue("RPT_LATEST_HA", params.getId_latest_ha());  
task.setParameterValue("RPT_LATEST_EXAMN", params.getId_latest_examen());  
task.setParameterValue("RPT_PREVIOUS_HA", params.getId_previous_ha());  
task.setParameterValue("RPT_PREVIOUS_EXAMN", params.getId_previous_examen());

PDFRenderOption options = new PDFRenderOption();
options.setOutputStream(outputStream);
options.setOutputFormat("pdf");
task.setRenderOption(options);
task.run();
task.close();
```

and is in the task.run(); line that it takes forever, and i tried for about 1 hour or 1 hour and a half and it does not end.
If anyone can help it will be really apreciated.

Bye and thank you.

Comment: Is it the same if you try to generate a PDF with a simple demo report based on the sample database, or is this issue specific to one report?

Comment: Is only one report that we need right now, and the person who design the reports, he test it in his local machine with eclipse and the same database that i'm using.

Comment: I download the source of the birt runtime, and i make a debug. And i found that the problem is with the IText. And i do not know why.
The problem is with the images. In the line addimage is where it freezes
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfTemplate template;
template.addImage( image, width, 0, 0, height, 0, 0 );
And also in the close;
com.lowagie.text.Document doc;
doc.close();
Please help.
Thank you

Comment: When I see my name in the package that is mentioned, I know that you're using a version of iText that is no longer supported. See http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq

Comment: Yeah!!. Sorry but this version is included in the birt version we are using. org.eclipse.birt.runtime.v_4.2.1[a lot of numbers].jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and it wasn't neither of the two API's.

We were trying to generate a pdf file for worker, and we were zipping all the pdf file of all the workers, and this zip was saved in a blob in the database. That was the problem.

If the zip is saved in the File System it works ok.

thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If this report works in a birt Eclipse designer then it should work with a birt runtime API, the issue is in your code.

- You need to close yourself the outputStream sent to the PDFRenderOption object, when the task has terminated
- Add this line to your code:

  *options.setSupportedImageFormats("PNG;JPG;BMP");*